# Connection Exception trying to send email in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using the Javamail API to try and send an email in my java code. The problem is occurring on a particular line.

Part of the code is:

```
 URLConnection c = u.openConnection();          
 c.setDoInput(false);                            
 c.setDoOutput(true);               
 c.connect();
```

---

The error is occurring at the c.connect() line of the code. the error I get is:

```
connect. Timeout = -1

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

And this is all the description I get. I'm not sure how to fix this problem. Please help.

Comment: Why are you using URLConnection to send an email?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this page](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2001/jw-1026-javamail.html) to get an example how to send E-Mails.
You should use the class Transport to send emails.

```
public static void send(String smtpServer, String to, String from
   , String subject, String body) throws Exception
  {

      Properties props = System.getProperties();
      // -- Attaching to default Session, or we could start a new one --
      props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpServer);
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
      // -- Create a new message --
      Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
      // -- Set the FROM and TO fields --
      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
      msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
        InternetAddress.parse(to, false));
      // -- We could include CC recipients too --
      // if (cc != null)
      // msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC
      // ,InternetAddress.parse(cc, false));
      // -- Set the subject and body text --
      msg.setSubject(subject);
      msg.setText(body);
      // -- Set some other header information --
      msg.setHeader("X-Mailer", "LOTONtechEmail");
      msg.setSentDate(new Date());
      // -- Send the message --
      Transport.send(msg);
      System.out.println("Message sent OK.");
  }
```

**EDIT:**

Because of your comment...

Check if someone blocks the port 25 (Firewall, other application)

the authentication could also be a problem, than you can find a good exampl [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html#JavaMailAuthenticator)

```
props.put( "mail.smtp.auth", "true" );
Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator( "me@sender.net", "mypassword" );
```

Comment: I have tried an example like this but I get the error "Could not connect to SMTP host: ... port: 25" and it occurs at the Transport.sned(msg) line

Comment: Then try again. Check your connection properties. And check if there's a firewall. this is the way to do it.